# Cookie on same domain (First party) inside iframe not sending or saving

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, xss, samesite

I have a SPA which uses a session token stored in a cookie for authentication with an API.

The SPA is on spa.domain.com, and the API is on api.domain.com; they share a common TLD.

The SPA sends a request CSRF token to the API, then sends a login request with the CSRF token and credentials to authenticate and create the cookie which is sent with subsequent requests.

This all works fine.

The problem I'm facing is that the SPA has an iframe, to which the src points back at a separate section of the SPA (The need for this is not the point of my question, i know it's convoluted but needs must).

The document loaded in the iframe has the same subdomain as the parent, i.e. spa.domain.com loads an iframe of spa.domain.com/iframecontents.

The page within the iframe skips cookies in Chrome and FF (Safari sends them an it works fine). I've looked at various threads about SameSite and Secure cookies and 3rd party vs first party but it is my understanding that this should simply be a first party cookie, i own the domains etc. (Although I have just realised locally the API is on one port and the SPA is on another port so that might account for different domains... just did a bit more reading, port is not included just the hostname)

It seems the cookies it already has for that domain are not being sent with the request

[image]

> This cookie was blocked because it had the "SameSite=Lax"" attribute and  the request was made from a different site and was not initiated by a top-level navigation.

and the cookies it receives to replace the ones the server thought were missing appear to be being ignored too

[image]

> This attempt to set a cookie via a Set-Cookie header was blocked because it had the "SameSite=Lax" attribute but came from a cross-site response which was not the response to a top-level navigation.

The cookies look like this

[image]

```
path=/; domain=localhost; secure; httponly; samesite=lax
```

If I change `samesite` to `none` then it does work, but then I assume that means I'm just opening up my session cookies to being stolen by third parties in xss attacks? Seems nonsensical to me.

Why is an iframe on the same domain not working with lax and how might I work around this issue?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this? I have a similar situation. My site can be put into an iframe or visited directly, need to be able to share the session token between the two ways a user may interact with the site.

Comment: Unfortunately not, no.